# Is there a Force power in Star Wars that allows one to create objects by "crystallizing" the force?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force

I don't know how best to describe it, but is there a Force power, either light or dark side, that allows a force user to shape the force and crystallize it into solid objects, like blades of pure Force? not permanently, but for a short period of time.

It can be from either Canon or Legends.
Cheers!

Comment: Luke's force-projected dice, which Leia held?

Comment: @Adamant Oh, yeah. I completely forgot about that. Though was it really projected or was it teleported? I remember it laying on the ground when Kylo and his forces took the base. If it had been only projected, shouldn't it have vanished once Luke was gone?

Comment: Didn't they also dissolve when Kylo held them?

Comment: Kylo held the dices for a few seconds before they dissolved into nothingness

Comment: Ah, completely forgot about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if RPG sources are considered as EU/Legends these days, but, after looking at my RPG material, all I could find was a power that allowed the user to energize an existing weapon, effectively turning it into a temporary lightsaber, and one that created energy shield made of Force energy.

The energizing power requires an existing physical weapon, like a sword or blade or claws or whatever, to act as the core around which the energy of the Force is wrapped; the shield one has does not require a physical component.

The RPG material I have contain many sourcebooks based on comics, novels and other EU material produced over the years. They went as far to make stats and description for stuff seen only once in one comic, and background ships that can barely be seen on a comic page or are mentioned in passing in novels.

Comment: Yeah, I read about this power on Wookieepedia. It's not exactly what I'm looking for, but since a force user can create a force shield, it shouldn't be too far-fetched for them to be able to shape the force into a blade. Thanks for the comment, Sava. If you don't mind me asking, what RPG material did you look through?

Comment: @KyleSentient The whole of WEG Star Wars D6 material, some of the Wizards of the Coast stuff that I found online, I believe it was for a card game, and a massive doc file that I found online a few years ago that has a huge list of Force powers, including some fanmade ones. I don't have any of the new D20 game.